# Trying to "follow" someone on Twitter using new iOS 5 API, getting 406 return error. Why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, twitter, ios5

Trying to "follow" someone on Twitter using new iOS 5 API, getting 406 return error. Why?

Is my code correct? Need to find out why this isn't working....

```
    - (void)followOnTwitter:(id)sender
{
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if(granted) {
        // Get the list of Twitter accounts.
        NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

        // For the sake of brevity, we'll assume there is only one Twitter account present.
        // You would ideally ask the user which account they want to tweet from, if there is more than one Twitter account present.
        if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {
            // Grab the initial Twitter account to tweet from.
            ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];

            NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [tempDict setValue:@"sortitapps" forKey:@"screen_name"];
            [tempDict setValue:@"true" forKey:@"follow"];

            TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/friendships/create.format"] 
                                                         parameters:tempDict 
                                                      requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];


            [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

            [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]];
                NSLog(@"%@", output);

                }];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

All of the code looks correct. Are the parameters incorrect? Is the URL correct? Need some direction here....

Comment: As explain below, the error comes from the wrong URL which should be ```http://api.twitter.com/1/friendships/create.json``` instead of ```http://api.twitter.com/1/friendships/create.format```

Comment: As explained below, it's https not http so the above comment is wrong

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question... I changed the URL to https://api.twitter.com/1/friendships/create.json and it worked.

Don't forget it's https, not just http.

Comment: Just noticed it was there originally, quick note so you dont replace with the URL and omit that part. You might want to edit the answer for clarity. Works great, thanks.

Answer (score 20):

For iOS 6 twitter follow

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if(granted) {
        // Get the list of Twitter accounts.
        NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

        // For the sake of brevity, we'll assume there is only one Twitter account present.
        // You would ideally ask the user which account they want to tweet from, if there is more than one Twitter account present.
        if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {
            // Grab the initial Twitter account to tweet from.
            ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];

            NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [tempDict setValue:@"MohammadMasudRa" forKey:@"screen_name"];
            [tempDict setValue:@"true" forKey:@"follow"];
            NSLog(@"*******tempDict %@*******",tempDict);

            //requestForServiceType

            SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/friendships/create.json"] parameters:tempDict];
            [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];
            [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %i Error %d", [urlResponse statusCode],error.code];
                NSLog(@"%@error %@", output,error.description);
            }];
        }

    }
}];
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Amit.  Quick clarification - does this need authentication first with twitter?

Answer (score 3):

As twitter has updated their API to v1.1, the request should be made now using the URL below. Note that request should be with 'https://' and due to API v1.1 replace your 1 to 1.1 in your URL.

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json

Comment: The above URL is recommended for iOS6 and above.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
- (BOOL)openTwitterClientForUserName:(NSString*)userName {
NSArray *urls = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                 @"twitter://user?screen_name={username}", // Twitter
                 @"tweetbot:///user_profile/{username}", // TweetBot
                 @"echofon:///user_timeline?{username}", // Echofon              
                 @"twit:///user?screen_name={username}", // Twittelator Pro
                 @"x-seesmic://twitter_profile?twitter_screen_name={username}", // Seesmic
                 @"x-birdfeed://user?screen_name={username}", // Birdfeed
                 @"tweetings:///user?screen_name={username}", // Tweetings
                 @"simplytweet:?link=http://twitter.com/{username}", // SimplyTweet
                 @"icebird://user?screen_name={username}", // IceBird
                 @"fluttr://user/{username}", // Fluttr
                 /** uncomment if you don't have a special handling for no registered twitter clients */
                 //@"http://twitter.com/{username}", // Web fallback, 
                 nil];

UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
for (NSString *urlString in urls) {
    NSString *candidate = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{username}" withString:userName];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:candidate];
    if ([application canOpenURL:url]) {
        [application openURL:url];
        return YES;
    }
}
return NO;
}
```

https://gist.github.com/ChrisRicca/9144169

Comment: For this code to work you have to edit your `info.plist` file and add the url prefixes as entries in an array called: `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`.