# Take screenshot than post it to twitter, without saving. iOS

Tags: ios, twitter, screenshot

Helle there,

I want to write a code for making a screenshot and than post it to twitter without saving the pic to the library. 
I don't know how to start... 
Can anybody help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Divide your task to simpler tasks and take a few minutes to search the SO. 1) Get a screenshot image (many examples). 2) Post image to twitter (many examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to make this screenshot: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2203293/1117854 
Then you are ready to send it. There are many tutorials on that: 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/posting-images-using-twrequest 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8236754/1117854 
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-5-and-the-twitter-framework-first-steps/